# ESP32 with external power supply and serial communication between ESP32 and PC

Tags: power-supply, usb, uart, esp8266, esp32

I would like ESP32 with +3v3 external power supply.
I don't want to use PC-USB's power supply through +3V3 voltage regulator.
Is it possible to make serial communication between ESP32 and PC using usb-uart serial converter(CH340G specifically)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the way it works as common ground.

Ref: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/an-introduction-to-ground/